# Ue4 TiledMap Generation in 3d

Tags: grid, unreal-engine4, tiles, blueprint

How i can generate a Island shaped 2d Map with tiled cubes? Does someone can give me tipps or links or some other help please?

I already tried it with Noise but it ends in weird results cause i dont get how i use it in a 2d way.

Also i tried to give each tiles numbers so i knew what was the last placed tile.
But that ended in a big Chaos.

What i dont understand right now is how to "move" in that grid or how to know what was last and what could be the next and ye. 
I really guess there is a simple way to handle that all which i dont realize at the moment?

I work for right now only with BP.

Thanks